# Scraping loop over a vector of links with Rselenium gives "Error Summary: NoSuchWindow"

Tags: r, for-loop, web-scraping, rselenium

I'm scraping newspapers and I'm facing a problem.

I have this code that actually works but rmDR$navigate has an issue with looping over various links, some times the loop gets the first two links properly scraped, some times four, but then it throws this error:

> Summary: NoSuchWindow
>   Detail: A request to switch to a different window could not be satisfied because the window could not be found

I'm pretty new with rselenium so I'm not sure if the loop I'm trying can be set to work. I've done something similar with Rvest an works but the webpage I'm facing here requires a dynamic web scraping.

```
remDr<- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "192.168.99.100",port = 4445L)
remDr$open()

#newsvector is a vector filled with links to the news I'm scraping

newsvector<-c('https://www.biobiochile.cl/noticias/nacional/region-metropolitana/2019/12/19/incendios-san-jose-de-maipo-balance-cifra-en-mas-de-mil-las-hectareas-consumidas-y-1-casa-quemada.shtml','https://www.biobiochile.cl/noticias/nacional/region-de-magallanes/2019/12/18/hercules-c-130-armada-pronostica-vientos-sobre-100-kmh-y-olas-de-hasta-6-metros-en-','https://www.biobiochile.cl/noticias/nacional/region-de-los-lagos/2019/12/18/incendio-consumio-gran-parte-de-camion-en-puerto-montt.shtml','https://www.biobiochile.cl/noticias/nacional/chile/2019/12/18/los-argumentos-de-las-diputadas-que-votaron-contra-la-paridad-de-genero-para-proceso-','https://www.biobiochile.cl/noticias/nacional/chile/2019/12/18/senadores-aprueban-indicaciones-sobre-paridad-pueblos-originarios-e-independientes-previo-a-')

newsscraped<-data.frame()

#The loop in question:

for(i in newsvector) {
  remDr$navigate(i)
  titulo<-unlist(remDr$findElement(using = "xpath",value="/html/body/div[6]/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]")$getElementText())
  date<-unlist(remDr$findElement(using = "xpath",value="/html/body/div[6]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]")$getElementText())
  texto<-unlist(remDr$findElement(using = "xpath",value="/html/body/div[6]/div[2]/div[3]/div[5]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]")$getElementText())
  texto<-as.character(texto)
  titulo<-as.character(titulo)
  date<-as.character(date)
  todo<-data.frame(texto,titulo,date, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  newsscraped<-rbind(newsscraped, todo, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: I don't think anyone will be able to help you unless you give us at least some of `newsvector`. Can you edit your question, adding some of the links you are trying to scrape?

Comment: thanks, i included five links, ussualy the loop just gets the first two